# Code searching for the function in a different Class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement ALS on Spark. I have used *ml* class instead of *mllib* because the CSV file contains String in one column. Rating class in *mllib* do not accept String as a parameter.

I want to use predict function from *org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel* class but while running it is searching in *org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD*.

This is the code I am using.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
object LoadCsv{
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Load CSV")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println("READING FILE...............................");
    val data = sc.textFile("file.csv")

    val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, item, rate) =>
        Rating[String](user, item, rate.toFloat)
    })


    //val (userFactors, itemFactors) = ALS.train(ratings)
    //Build the recommendation model using ALS
    val rank = 10
    val numIterations = 10
    val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)

    // Evaluate the model on rating data
    val usersProducts = ratings.map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
      (user, product)
    }
    // GETTING ERROR OVER HERE.
    val predictions =
      model.predict(usersProducts).map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
        ((user, product), rate)
      }
    val ratesAndPreds = ratings.map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
      ((user, product), rate)
    }.join(predictions)
    val MSE = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((user, product), (r1, r2)) =>
      val err = (r1 - r2)
      err * err
    }.mean()
    println("Mean Squared Error = " + MSE)

    // Save and load model
    //model.save(sc, "/home/shishir/spark-Projects/op")
    //val sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
    // $example off$
  }
```

}

On running the code, I am getting this error:

```
LoadCsv.scala:34: value predict is not a member of (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[Float])], org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[Float])])

[error] model.predict(usersProducts).map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your imports are "incorrect", you are using this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating
```

When you should be using this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
```

You can use the other package, it's just that the result won't be a model but (as the error says) and RDD.

You can read up online why there are two ML packages (from what I remember the `mllib` package is the older one and contains some design flaws so they reimplement in `ml` so they can use pipelines).

Comment: The data set is stored in a csv file in the format: Name(String),Value1(Integer),Value2(Double). When I use **mllib**, I get java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString error because the Rating class needs the parameters in the format: (user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double) and the first column of my file contains Name.

Comment: That is why I am using *ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating* instead of *mllib.recommendation.Rating*. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: @user300194 that's a different problem, either map user string to an int or rewrite your algorithm to use `ml` package instead

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing MLLib and ML style approach. If your data uses supported ID types (it doesn't look like it is the case here) you can use MLLib implementation:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{ALS => OldALS}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{
  MatrixFactorizationModel => OldModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{Rating => OldRating}

val ratings: RDD[OldRating] = ???

val model: OldModel = OldALS()
  .setAlpha(0.01)
  .setIterations(numIterations)
  .setRank(rank)
  .run(ratings)
```

If your data uses non-standard ID and you want  an access to user friendly API it is better to use `DataFrames`:

```
val ratings: RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating[String]] = ???
val df = ratings.toDF

val als: org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS = new ALS()
  .setAlpha(0.01)
  .setMaxIter(numIterations)
  .setRank(rank)
val model: org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel = als.fit(df)
```

Finally you can use your current approach but you'll have to operate on user factors and item factors directly without helpers like `predict`.

Comment: yes but as you can see from the comments in the code it still shouldn't be private, that implementation is for String user IDs, although not recommended for performance reasons.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Yes, I can agree with the last statement :)